# zero locus of a sheaf homomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The title says it all.

I'm just starting to go through the existence-proof of the quot scheme

(http://www.math.utah.edu/~bertram/courses/hilbert/ps/hilbert.ps).

On page 7, almost at the bottom of the page a scheme is defined as the zero locus of a homomorphism of sheaves.

What exactly is the zero locus of a sheaf homomorphism?

Greetings

Dan

Answer (score 6):

Given a sheaf homomorphism $F\to G$, there exists a unique ideal sheaf $I$ (thus defining a unique closed subscheme) such that $F/IF\to G/IG$ is the zero map and $I$ is  minimal with respect to this property. This subscheme is usually called the zero locus of a sheaf homomorphism. For example, locally, if $F,G$ are locally free, then such a homomorphism is given by a matrix of functions (all locally) and then the zero locus would be the scheme where all the entries of this matrix vanish.

Comment: I suspect that your sheaves $F$ and $G$ are implictely assumed to be $O_X$-modules... That was of course the case in White's application.